# How can I add a custom attribute to a <span> and read it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have a jQuery/PHP site that uses `<span>` elements for the navigation links. I need to have a `value` attribute to use

```
$(".navLink").click(function() {
    window.location.href = "/index.php?page=" + this.value //or whatever
});
```

I can't use `this.id` because it conflicts with other HTML elements. Is there any way to create and use a "dummy" HTML attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a data-* attribute. Something like data-href would be good. jQuery gives you a nice interface for reading the values.

```
this.data('href')
```

will read the value of

```
data-href="some.value"
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/ for more.

Comment: How exactly would you do that?? I'm pretty new to this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `data-`. So in your HTML, you'd define it like:

```
<span class="navLink" data-link="google.com">click me</span>
```

And then via jQuery you just do:

```
window.location.href = "/index.php?page=" + $(this).data("link");
```

Answer (score 2):

pure js:

```
el.setAttribute('value', the-value);
```

jquery:

```
$(el).attr('value', the-value);
```

but better make something easily recognisable like `my-value` as a name of your attributes, to avoid conflicts and make them easier to notice in the code